# Why does Xcode 5 keep giving me these errors?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-analytics

So, last week I got some warnings on Xcode 5.1 beta and compile linking errors. It turned out to be related to the Google Analytics SDK that I had added to my project.

To resolve the issue I removed the Google library `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` from my build phases. I then went into Build Settings and removed the path to the Google Analytics under `Library Search Paths` - After that I readied the Google library and re-compiled. All errors solved.

However, every cople of hours / days this same error keeps coming back and I have to keep redoing the steps taken above. Rather frustrating.

I'm using Xcode 5.1 beta 5.

The erros in the build log that I get: 
[image]

Comment: Have you set other linker flag ?

Comment: Not that I can remember. What linker flag are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use xcode 5.02 stable version and then add google analytic accordingly then hopefully these errors will be resolved,

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking of doing that. 5.1 is proving to be quite unstable.

Comment: Yes same problems I am facing too before installing xcode 5.02.Hopefully it will help you too.